# Data parsing of binary files in C++ : and the right STL for it?

Tags: c++, data-structures, vector, stl

I am trying to develop a Request-Response system similar to Client-Server approach, where in Client requests for its data from the Server. The response from Server is read from a file in binary and sent to respective Client, and the file size is nearly `35 KB` consisting of 120 lines.

The prototype of the file is like:

```
line-1: abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
line-2: abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
line-3: abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
line-4: abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
line-5: (FOR CLIENT-235)abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
line-6: abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
line-7: (FOR CLIENT-124)abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
line-8: abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
.
.
.
line-119: (FOR CLIENT-180)abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
line-120: abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

First four lines are for Server and next 116 are for Client(s).
Starting from 5th, the data required for particular client will be two lines i.e. if request comes from CLIENT-235, 
Server has to save line-5 and line-6 data for future transactions in a Container and send to it. If the same client requests again, 
send line-5 and line-6 without reading the whole file. Similar approach for other Clients.

Can maintaining an `Index` file will be easier which will index for particular line and information -Do I need a `Map`?

I want to know what is the best way to accomplish this (atleast better way) using `Vector` or simple `structures`?
Because the number of lines in the file may increase, so do I need sort of Dynamic Array?

Comment: "The response from Server is read from a file in binary" Your prototype file doesn't look very binary. Also, lines do not exist in binary files, if you don't prohibit the use of the bit pattern for `\n`. Is your file encoded in something like UTF-8 or ASCII?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use STL's map to achieve what you want. 
Since each client's response will be two lines of strings, you can create a struct containing two variables to store it. Then you can insert the struct into the map, with "CLIENT-X" as the index element. Lastly, use the index to retrieve the client's data. Below is an example:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct data
{
    string firstLine, secondLine;
    data(){ }
};

int main()
{
    ifstream file("input.txt");

    std::map<string,data> mymap;    
    stringstream ss;
    string index;
    data buffer;
    int client = 1;

    if(file.is_open())
    {
        string server[4];

        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) // read the first 4 lines for the server
            getline(file, server[i]);

        while(getline(file, buffer.firstLine))
        {
            getline(file, buffer.secondLine);

            // define the index value for retrieval
            ss.str("");
            ss << "CLIENT-" << client;

            // insert the client's data into the map
            mymap.insert(pair<string,data>(ss.str(), buffer));
            client++;
        }

        // retrieve the client's data
        buffer = mymap["CLIENT-1"]; // example on how to access

        // here you can do what you want, like sending to the client
        //


        file.close();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The clients in the OP's example are not sorted. Additionally, I don't see a reason why the clients should be indexed using a `string` instead of an integer.

Comment: Changed the !file.eof() part. I know it's not sorted, but what I'm doing here is just giving the example, not doing all the OP's work. OP is free to customize it according to his/her needs, be it in integer or in string (for example IP address or so), as OP also mentioned it's the prototype of the file, not actual file, so it can be different. The point here is the idea, not an actual solution that can just be copy-pasted.

Comment: I agree that SO is not to let someone else do your job entirely (but about help for a specific problem). As far as I understand the OP, one of the problems is using a data structure that allows inserting of the unsorted client responses. IMHO, the solution to this problem is only partly shown in your example. The update with no `if(!file.eof())` is better, but better still would be to check the stream after everything is read, e.g. via `while(true) { /*read 2 lines*/ if(!file) break; /*insert data into map*/ }` Another check should be done right after the for-loop.